# Windows 7 - What happens when you delete the AppData folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, home-directory, home-folder

What happens when you delete the entire C:/Users/Username/AppData folder?

I haven't used my Windows boot in a while and want to make space on my harddrive. But if I decide to use Windows again, I don't want all the programs to be broken.

I don't care if the program settings return to defaults, but I'd like to keep my Firefox and Chrome saved passwords on the Windows boot.

Comment: Maybe don't delete locallow just FWIW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will lose all your application settings. If you want to keep FireFox or Google settings make sure you sync them before you wipe out your AppData folder. You should also backup this folder first, just in case.

Comment: Some applications install into AppData. For example, OneDrive and Kindle. Chrome can install in AppData if the user does not have admin rights.